# Android - How to display pdf contents from .js file in webview

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, mobile, webview

My requirement is to display the webcontents from a package in Android app's webview.

1. The package folder contains html,fonts,pdf folders with respective files inside it.
2. I am accessing the entire contents by pointing to the index.html file

   ```
   mWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/appFolder/html5/index.html")
   ```
3. Working fine except the pdf rendering.I have searched on internet but all the answers are related with .pdf extention files
4. My problem is we are having pdf contents in .js extention like pdf.js

How to display the pdf contents from .js file?

Comment: What do you consider to be 'the package folder'?

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for the response..package folder is nothing but the directory under which i have all html, fonts, pdf directories ..I have placed this package directory inside assets folder..

Comment: @greenapps the web developers gave me the pdf contents in .js extention file...for example  pdfasset.js..i have show that file in webview..but its not rendering...i have set webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  eventhough its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue finally resolved, the pdf contents are now displaying.
I have added the following two lines in onCreate()

```
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

It worked...!!  Thanks..